# Java Sorting a collection with duplicate elements. If duplicates, sort by order of appearance

Tags: java, sorting

I have a java collection of type Element and the idea is to sort it in ascending order. However, duplicated elements should be sorted by order of appearance. Let me explain a little bit better with some code:

```java
public class Sorting {
    // Element class
    public static class Element {
       int value;
       String position;
    }
    // Comparator class
    public static class ElementComparator implements Comparator<Element> {
       @Override
       public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
          if (e1.value != e2.value) return e1.value - e2.value;
          return 1; // Elements have same value, so with this condition
                    // am I guaranteeing that duplicated elements are
                    // sorted by order of appearance ?
                    // I have been testing with this approach and it has worked fine
                    // but I am not sure how the sort could behave
                    // for other scenarios, eg, multithread environment
                    // I would like to know if this is a safe approach
       }
       @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Element{" + "number=" + number + ", position=" + position + '}';
        }
    }
    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Element> elements = new LinkedList<>();
        elements.add(new Element(3, "first 3"));
        elements.add(new Element(2, "first 2"));
        elements.add(new Element(2, "second 2"));
        elements.add(new Element(1, "first 1"));
        elements.add(new Element(1, "second 1"));
        elements.sort(new ElementComparator());
        for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // It will print:
        // Element{number=1, position=first 1}
        // Element{number=1, position=second 1}
        // Element{number=2, position=first 2}
        // Element{number=2, position=second 2}
        // Element{number=3, position=first 3}
        // Notice that duplicated elements are sorted by order of appearance
    }
}
```

In case this approach is not safe, I was considering to create a Wrapper class to do the sort. This wrapper class is something like:

```java
public class ElementWrapperForSorting {
   int value;
   String position;
   int positionOfAppearence;
}
```

That way, if the value is the same between elements, I can consider the field positionOfAppearence.

Comment: The term you are looking for is a *stable sort*. And the default sort algorithm used by Java is a merge sort, which is already stable, so you can just use the standard sort method.

Comment: @Alex Thank you clarify the term!

Comment: The default sorting algorithm used by Java is actually Timsort.

Comment: FYI, Wikipedia explains [*stable sort algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and [*Timsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the wrapper. `List.sort` is stable, so equal elements are not reordered. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)).